# Completion Suggester - mixing prefix suggestions with non-prefix suggestions

Tags: elasticsearch

What's the best approach to mix prefix suggestions with non-prefix suggestions.

For example say we have the following terms:

cancer prevention

bladder cancer

breast cancer

with the prefix suggestions it will only ever return "cancer prevention" however I would like to be able to return "bladder cancer" and "breast cancer" but with them being lower in terms of weight or relevancy. So the order would be:

cancer prevention

bladder cancer

breast cancer

Answer (score 0):

Try the Phrase Suggester to see if it's scoring order helps at all.  If not, you may need to package two separate suggestion requests in the API call (prefix and phrase), and then order/dedupe them in your client.

[Twitter Typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) has support for  client-side de-duplication (and multiple suggestion sources if you'd like to go that route.)